# How to declare a vector of unique_ptr's as class data member?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, unique-ptr

I'd like to have a vector of unique_ptr's as a member of a class I'm making.

```
class Foo {
    [...]

private:
    vector<unique_ptr<Bar>> barList;
}
```

But then I start getting cryptic error messages from the **VS2010** compiler:

```
error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
```

Along with a handful of error lines below that which dive into Microsoft's implementation of `std::_Copy_impl<>`...

I changed the member declaration to

```
vector<unique_ptr<Bar>>* barList;
```

And it compiles. But I can't help but wonder why I can't do it the way I originally wanted? For grins, I tried this and it works fine:

```
vector<Bar> barList;
```

But now I lose the convenience of `unique_ptr`. I want my cake and I want to eat it too!

Comment: I was looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553464/vector-as-a-class-member and the answer seems to think declaring a `vector` like I did is just fine to do. For some reason, though, it seems to trigger illegal copies when adding the `unique_ptr` part.

Comment: What do your copy constructor and assignment operator look like?

Comment: Private assignment, but copy constructor was the culprit. Switched from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` when I realized I was using the wrong ownership semantic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that somewhere, your code is attempting to call the "copy-assignment" operator of `Foo`.

This causes the compiler to attempt to generate a copy-assignment operator which calls the copy-assignment operators of all the subobjects of `Foo`. Eventually, this leads to an attempt to copy a `unique_ptr`, an operation which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The compiler was misleading me because the error was referencing the member declaration and made no mention of the offending code causing the copy. I imagine this is a deficiency in VS2010 and will hopefully improve with newer releases. My `Foo` class has a copy constructor, and I was trying to copy the vector out of the source `Foo`. Shared ownership seems to be the better solution, so switching to `shared_ptr` did the trick.

Comment: It looks like a bug in VS2010 I get this error even if my code never tries to call copy-assigment. Disabling the operator= with declaring as private (hence =delete is not supported) solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

`unique_ptr` doesn't have copy semantics, so you can't use any methods that would copy the contained object. You *can* do this with rvalue references by using `std::move` in the place(s) it's trying to make a copy. Without seeing your code I can't say where that would be.

If it compiles in the second form either you didn't exercise the same code or there's a compiler bug. Both should fail the same way.

Your third example, storing by value is the simplest way unless your objects are large and expensive to store/copy around by value.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is the one which doesn't obey normal copy semantics, `unique_ptr` simply doesn't **have** copy semantics

Comment: Your's and Mankarse's answers are very very similar. His, however, made me realize I needed to go on a witch hunt for the offending code (your answer addressed that issue more subtly). You both deserve the accepted answer, though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Often a `std::move(iUniquePtr)` is missing somewhere (e. g. when using push_back).

Answer (score 1):

The usual problems are `erase()`, `emplace*()` and `push*()`. These will try to shift vector elements around, as one or more than one of them are erased or inserted. While this should work, as `std::unique_ptr` is movable and shifting is not strictly required, it sometimes does not and the reason are bugs in `STL` implementations. You may be better off with a `std::list` for this reason, use `std::shared_ptr`s, use a `std::vector` alternative, file a bug, or just use raw pointers, a surprisingly easy and effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

An excerpts from www.cplusplus.com

```
std::unique_ptr::operator=
```

*unique_ptr assignment
The object acquires the ownership of x's content, including both the stored pointer and the stored deleter (along with the responsibility of deleting the object at some point). Any object owned by the unique_ptr object before the call is deleted (as if unique_ptr's destructor was called).*

But there is a warning too:

*This page describes a feature introduced by the latest revision of the C++ standard (2011). Older compilers may not support it.*

MSVC 2010 defines `operator=` as private (non-copyable) but supports `swap` method.

Answer (score -3):

You can't use unique_ptr in vector because vector implementation strongly relies on values assign operator, which is private in `unique_ptr`. Use `shared_ptr` from boost or other smart ptr implementation from C++11.

Comment: C++11 containers are required to work with move-only types like `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I meant the way he used it. But still, thank You, I didn't know about emplace_back.

Comment: You don't need to use emplace_back.  You can use push_back as long as you give it r-values.